# Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The issuer is invalid"

Tags: sitecore-commerce, installation

I have installed `Sitecore commerce 9.1.0`. The setup is working fine but I am not able to configure Postman.

To configure postman I have

- disabled SSL Certificate validation in Postman
- `"AntiForgeryEnabled":false` in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceAuthoring_Sc910\wwwroot\config.json`

The `Get Token` api is working fine and `SitecoreIdToken` is also set to correct value

Is there anything that I have missed out?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You will need to pass valid Bearer Token with your request parameters.

Comment: I have verified that the token is generated and `SitecoreIdToken` is set .

Comment: can you please provide screenshot of header values you are passing

Comment: In this case, please check expiry of the token and see if you are passing a valid token.Can you also share the screen shot of postman where you are passing token.

Comment: @S.Kazmi I have added the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the Sitecore Commerce Engine instance security fact. Please ensure that the value of **SitecoreIdServerHost** postman environment variable is exactly similar to **SitecoreIdentityServerUrl** and also whitelisted under **AllowedOrigins** property (under config.json) of your Commerce Engine Instance which you're trying to access (Auth/Shops etc.).

In my case I have two bindings (localhost as well as friendly host name) on SitecoreIdentityServer instance and I was receiving the token using localhost binding (which comes by default in postman) but only the friendly host name was listed under Commerce Engine. This is also the common issue if you are working with scaled architecture. Hope it helps!

Comment: This was the answer for me. The SitecoreIdServerHost in my postman environment was without "https://" while the value of SitecoreIdentityServerUrl included "https://". Adding "https://" in postman solved the problem.